# Executing a .rb file (Ruby file) with PRY in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

I was wondering how I can load a Ruby file into PRY to use the debugger function on my Windows 7 computer with Command Prompt.  I want to use PRY to go through my program step by step and following the tutorials online on how to do it aren't working for me (probably because all of them are using Mac Terminal)

I use SublimeText 2 to write everything up and then save it as a .rb file and I was told that if I wanted to debug the file I just made, I need to run it through IRB or PRY.  Not, I already ran "gem install debugger". And the Ruby I have installed is 1.9.3 - p545.  Do I need to add an extra line of code that says "binding.pry" (I saw that in some of the samples that I could find on stackoverflow).  All I'm looking for is a simple step-by-step process.  Thank you for reading this, I look forward to the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you've installed [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) and [`pry-debugger`](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) gems
2. At the top of your file, add statements for `require 'pry'` and `require 'pry-debugger'`
3. In your code, wherever you want to start ddebugging, just add a statement `binding.pry`
4. Now, you can run your file like `ruby filename.rb` and the debugger should open

Comment: You'll eventually need to `require 'pry'` as well, depending on your configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much mu and fab.  That helps a lot!  I'll reply here again if I run into another issue.  :)